# Calculate the number of messages generated during flooding over a graph

Tags: graph-theory

I want to find an algorithm to calculate the number of messages generated during flooding.[image]

This picture is a question I found on the Internet, which is what I want to resolve. I think maybe a modified Dijkstra algorithm can do it but I don't know how. Moreover, is this question a kind of typical problem in graph theory? If so, what is the name of this type of question?

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that a node will forward the message to all adjacent nodes except for those that were in the path of the received message and will discard messages that it has already seen then these messages will be sent/received:

| Time | Current Node | Message Path | Sent To | Due on | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | X | X | V | 3 |  |
| 0 | X | X | W | 6 |  |
| 0 | X | X | Y | 6 |  |
| 3 | V | XV | T | 7 |  |
| 3 | V | XV | U | 6 |  |
| 3 | V | XV | W | 7 |  |
| 3 | V | XV | Y | 4 |  |
| 4 | Y | XVY | T | 11 |  |
| 4 | Y | XVY | Z | 16 |  |
| 6 | U | XVU | S | 10 |  |
| 6 | U | XVU | T | 8 |  |
| 6 | U | XVU | W | 9 |  |
| 6 | W | XW | V | 10 |  |
| 6 | W | XW | U | 9 |  |
| 6 | Y | XY | - | - | Discarded as already seen |
| 7 | T | XVT | S | 8 |  |
| 7 | T | XVT | U | 9 |  |
| 7 | T | XVT | Y | 14 |  |
| 7 | T | XVT | Z | 12 |  |
| 7 | W | XVW | - | - | Discarded as already seen |
| 8 | S | XVTS |  |  | Reached target |
| 8 | T | XVUT | - | - | Discarded as already seen |
| 9 | U | XWU | - | - | Discarded as already seen |
| 9 | U | XVTU | - | - | Discarded as already seen |
| 9 | W | XVUW | - | - | Discarded as already seen |
| 10 | S | XVUS | - | - | Discarded as already seen |
| 10 | V | XWV | - | - | Discarded as already seen |
| 11 | T | XVYT | - | - | Discarded as already seen |
| 12 | Z | XVTZ | Y | 24 |  |
| 14 | Y | XVTY | - | - | Discarded as already seen |
| 16 | Z | XVYZ | - | - | Discarded as already seen |
| 24 | Y | XVTZY | - | - | Discarded as already seen |

That makes a total of 19 messages sent. The message is received by `S` at time = 8 and the last message is received by the network at time = 24.

As for an algorithm, when a node sends a message:

- It checks it has not received the message before; and
- If it has not, addresses a copy of the message to each of the adjacent nodes that are not previous recipients of the message;
- Then hands those messages to a "postman" to be delivered on the current time plus the time delay on the edge;
- When the "postman" gets to the time a message is due then it delivers it to the destination and the algorithm repeats for each node that has received a message.